# Can I use multi-level Grid in GeneXus SmartDevice?

Tags: smart-device, genexus

I have the following situation:

I have a transaction that I want to show all the elements in a panel, when the user tap the element I want to load and show a level of this element in a grid, in the same panel.

The problem is not the tap, I can't even load 2 grids when the panel opens. I've tried almost everything: Attributes, variables, SDTs, DataSelectors... but nothing seems works.

[image]

Genexus allow use 2 grids in a panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to have the first grid variable based. And the second Grid SDT Based.

The second grid is loaded within the Grid1 Load Event and activated on Grid Selection.
This can be accomplished by using the Grid Selected layout feature.

Here you have a [step by step](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Default%20Selected%20Item%20Layout%20property)

Also, I've uploaded an [XPZ with your example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14729664/GridSelected.xpz). Tested on iOS X Evolution 3.

Comment: Thank You! It Worked! I tried this approach but I used a for each inside the load. Changed to data provider and worked like a charm! :)

Comment: I had another problem, I am not being able to let the inside grid totally open, tried set the inside grid property "autogrow" to true, and let the row outside with 0dip, exactly like your xpz. [Print](http://i.imgur.com/VIVMYWF.png?1)
Am I forgetting anything?

Comment: Actually I'm using Evo. 3 Update 1, testing on Nexus 4 Android 4.1.1.